# How do get all the members of a dimension in a single column

Tags: ssas, mdx

I want to get all the client names in separate rows of a single column.
I tried this in MDX

```
WITH MEMBER ClientName
AS [Client].[Client].CURRENTMEMBER.NAME

SELECT {[ClientName]} ON 0
FROM [UserActivity]
```

This gives me a single column called "ClientName" row with "All" value in it. What I want is multiple rows in this column , one per client name. How can I do this?

Ultimately, what I'm trying to get working is something like this..where each client name is show in a column 0 and corresponding measure in column 1

```
WITH MEMBER ClientName
AS [Client].[Client].CURRENTMEMBER.NAME

SELECT {([ClientName], [Measures].[Total Engaged Users])} ON 0
FROM [UserActivity]
```

Now I know that, this works if I put my dimension on ROWS but I dont want that since a client app I'm using doesn't respect that

```
SELECT {[Client].[Client].Members} ON 0, {[Measures].[Total Engaged Users]} ON 1
FROM [UserActivity]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the function `.CurrentMember` to function it needs a context so you'll need to include `[Client].[Client].MEMBERS` on rows:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].ClientName AS 
    [Client].[Client].CurrentMember.Name 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[ClientName]
   ,[Measures].[Total Engaged Users]
  } ON 0
 ,[Client].[Client].MEMBERS ON 1
FROM [UserActivity];
```

If there are some calculated members in the Client hierarchy then the `AllMembers` function is preferable to`Members`:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].ClientName AS 
    [Client].[Client].CurrentMember.Name 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[ClientName]
   ,[Measures].[Total Engaged Users]
  } ON 0
 ,[Client].[Client].ALLMEMBERS ON 1
FROM [UserActivity];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look at using DESCENDANTS. This will work if all the Clients you're looking for are leaves in the hierarchy:

```
DESCENDANTS ([Client].[Client].MEMBERS,,LEAVES)
```